# Vue 3: Slots Attributes - Can you pass data through props?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Is it possible to pass data through slots? For example, can I have a named slot called "button", and pass it an href that gets added to an `a` tag?

For example:

#### MyComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="text-lg" v-bind="$slots['heading'].attrs">
      <slot name="heading" />
    </h2>
    <a class="btn" v-bind="$slots['button'].attrs">
      <slot name="button" />
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### MyPage.vue

```js
<template>
  <MyComponent>
    <template #header class="font-bold">
      This is my heading
    </template>
    <template #button href="/about" class="bg-primary">
      About us
    </template>
  </MyComponent>
</template>
```

#### HTML Output

```html
<div>
    <h2 class="text-lg font-bold">
      This is my heading
    </h2>
    <a class="btn bg-primary" href="/about">
      About Us
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp1VE1v4zYQ/SsT9SAZjaV0gV4c20Cw2MMCTXtoe4pyoKWRrC1FCiSVxDX83zsk9UHZKSEB5HD43nDeDM/RU9elbz1Gm2irC9V0BjSavtvnIje5AGjaTioDz6evkmYChYFKyRbiNAtsFiJ+DPz/5NI8GaP05D1ZRt9cbDNPacnE1mDbcWaQVgDbANwZyDQ6wE9HZGUj6v12pik403qXR5UUZn2QvIRDve5U0zJ1yqNswLDjr2Ojgb72BAPOgJ8tIlgQHnpjpAj5jgorosvYQfYmjyb+kBVm2ifrBr3+lGobppIsi21aanPiCLqQHZbOsikRuySd7ro6Wxi3fMemPpoNWDMl+RK4z6F5/wMr/qmV7EW54fbQgfc4HiFpLOk+uo+uZP6sUsSg+pmSchkUn1QupNAGOFM1wg7II6kY17hymwTxXRhUb4wnyQp2e++Y0rq37nfB8h5+eXh48OeC0rkqnLJ5G/U7foHNqMs5Nvhh1ryONw7yQvJoUnPNrJxzeWytEQRrkQ6N9TEruc2OX8Ypm0U34nO4BZovogUYG/T3QS90v1Y9HeKfpdbNv7iBXx+6D7jzAjBhRgHp7uewIIRULeOPcK2uIQJRNXX6Q0tB2pJp0am3citCoH+UHGo0X3ulqDy+k9BMFCSUFM9UVwZLO/27K+lKNO01+uZZ1sgA6OtEI69I91vQhISfvFyWyW1EHDbtP1FTPe3259Fs8+3PyoOmekNFxwW+w3NvmGmk+GMwJ/okCgc6Y9rDkzngsvaqF4U9HzqcYdy1I5yP5GnZ2MQLLMyAN3r4IDtm704h2nykb0KWmCJPvfkbx9Z2Y8GlRm2S+GUuvdd4CddUyZ0/RU0f2EcqyTF9Z0ok8e8S0ANTedGjAEZCI35QhK6yXc4bqmHUd1ccdigqDiUeF5e9hItKqsTfzbYDIXsRb6OiiJ3HbreD2HVYTAnNMiglmCN1hN0kNPANYmf4wahv8BrJDkfyYgFf05aZ4phkL3n+vn79OatX9IKqb4xsnnA/pJ0SS6y/NdqkrCzd5ur2xhekV+wmejsGFOoXWw8uZw7kPozmE8D/zd1UNcMk8Qz3cJ5F2RjV42VGdQDjT3anjP3np9MuphcneHyiy39iVbby)

Vue doesn't have support of this. Though I guess several workarounds are possible. The easiest one is to manipulate attributes with DOM (which is bad, Vue render functions don't go well with DOM manipulations) and react on attribute changes with MutationObserver.
For that we insert into a slot a custom component `SlotAttrs`. Also this component could be inserted automatically if there's some slot attributes present:
This would become

```
<template #heading><SlotAttrs class="font-bold bg-primary"/>
```

this:

```
<template #heading class="font-bold bg-primary">
```

For that I could write a rollup plugin, please notify if you need this further elaboration.

SlotAttrs.vue

```
<script setup>

import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted, onUpdated, useAttrs } from 'vue';

const self = getCurrentInstance();
const attrs = useAttrs();

onMounted(()=>{

    const observer = new MutationObserver(syncAttrs);

    syncAttrs();

    function syncAttrs(){ 
        
        observer.disconnect();
        const parent = self.vnode.el.parentElement.closest('[slot-attrs]');
        if(!parent){
            console.warn('No element found to inject slot attributes!');
            return; 
        }
        for(const name in attrs){
            if(name === 'class'){ // do the same for style for example
                attrs[name].match(/[\w-]+/g).forEach(name => parent.classList.add(name));
            }else{
                parent.setAttribute(name, attrs[name]);
            }
        }
        observer.observe(parent, {attributes:true});
    }


}); 

</script>
<template></template>
```

MyComponent.vue

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from 'vue';

const large = ref(false);

setInterval(() => large.value = !large.value, 1000);

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 :class="{'text-lg':large}" slot-attrs>
       <slot name="heading" />
    </h2>
    <a class="btn" slot-attrs>
      <slot name="button" />
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.text-lg{
  font-size: 50px !important;
}

h2 {font-weight:normal; }

</style>
```

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
    
  import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';
  import SlotAttrs from './SlotAttrs.vue';

</script>

<template>
  <MyComponent>
    <template #heading><SlotAttrs class="font-bold bg-primary"/>
        This is my heading
    </template>
    <template #button><SlotAttrs href="/about" class="bg-primary" />
      About us
    </template>
  </MyComponent>
</template>

<style scoped>

:deep(.font-bold){
  font-weight: bold;
}

:deep(.bg-primary){
  background:lightblue;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Very cool :) Thanks for sharing. This isn't critical for me right now, so I don't need the work around, but I hope it will be supported in Vue core very soon.

Comment: yes, i've seen your issue in vue github :)